# Create a virtual machine along with a dual boot (win 8.1 + ubuntu) machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I wanted to know can i create a virtual machine on a dual boot machine?

At present, I'm running on windows 8.1 along with ubuntu 14.04. Now I require a virtual machine (one more pc to be specific) for testing purposes. Can I create a virtual machine on the same machine?

My machine configuration is as follows:

Processor: Intel core i3-4010U CPU 1.70 GHz

RAM: 4GB

System type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a virtual machine (VM) on the PC either under your Windows 8.1 OS or under your Ubuntu OS, or both. Virtualbox is a good choice if you haven't utilized or setup VMs before. I started out using virtualbox and then switched to KVM under Debian.

In some cases from what I understand you can even get the virtualization software to boot an OS from a raw disk partition.

Comment: I'm new to VM environment.. Haven't used/setup a virtual machine ever before. 
How does it differ setting up VM under windows OS or under ubuntu OS?
And, what does "get the virtualization to boot an OS from a raw disk partition" mean?

Comment: With Virtualbox it is pretty much the same. With some virtualization software an OS may not be supported as either a host or a guest or both for that matter. I would probably start out with whichever OS you use more frequently. You might even eventually revert back to a single boot system depending on your actual needs. 

Raw disk virtualization boot would be for example be taking a existing XP system, changing it into a dual boot system and then booting XP from the Ubuntu system you added via the virtualization software installed under Ubuntu.

Comment: @TimeThief: Did you make any progress on this? Given it a try?

Comment: I'm really sorry for reverting back late. Well, thank you soo much for your time and your answer. I have multi-boot my system with windows 8.1 + ubuntu + kali linux. All went fine and works good now :) Thank you.